# Want to Check whether the Account create date is within the Business Hour or Not

Tags: datetime, time

I am creating a account so while creation it should check whether the created date is within the Business Hour or not. If yes do Action 1 else Action 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
 BusinessHours.isWithin(businessHoursId, targetDate);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm#apex_System_BusinessHours_isWithin)